# Angular checkboxes error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a little problem with checkboxes :

I have an array of objet. I do a ng-repeat on this array and i associate checkboxes on each element.

```
<li ng-repeat="title in treeZone track by $index">

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="title.selected" ng-click="functionAdd($index, title.selected)"/> {{title}}

</li>
```

My problèm is that i would like to get all the selected checkboxes with a function.

To do it, I wrote that :

```
scope.funtionAdd = function() {

          scope.tree_array = "";

          angular.forEach(scope.treeZones, function(title) {

            if (title.selected) { 

              scope.tree_array = scope.tree_array  + title.name + " ";

            }

          });

        }
```

This function works well but it cause that error : "Property 'selected' does not exist on type 'Zone'" due to "title.selected"

Knowing that my Zone object have 3 properties : id, name,  parent.

How resolv this issue knowing that my only way to know if a Zone is selected, is with " title.selected " .

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep one unique property in treeZone and use it to set id of the checkboxes

```
<li ng-repeat="title in treeZone track by $index">
<input id="{{title.TYPE}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="title.selected" ng-click="functionAdd($index, title.selected)"/> {{title}}
</li>
```

then in javascript you can check what all checkboxes are selected:

```
scope.tree_array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < scope.treeZone .length; i++) {
            document.getElementById(scope.treeZone[i].TYPE).checked = true;
            scope.tree_arra.push({ "TYPE": scope.treeZone[i].name});
        }
```

Comment: Thx for your answer ! I got this error now : "Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'." Maybe because i'm using typescript ?

Comment: probably. try this  
var element = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById(scope.treeZone[i].TYPE);
var isChecked = element.checked;

Comment: Thanks again :) Now i've that : "Property 'TYPE' does not exist on type 'Zone'."

Comment: TYPE is just for reference. If name is unique in treeZone the you can set id = {{title.name}} and use same in controller to check if checkbox is selected.

Comment: I think the method with "document.getElementById" doesn't work with typescript

Comment: Then there will be some way to access control by id